# Recursive function to build hierarchical JSON tree?

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search

I have a nested json and I want to traversal treepath with key value is spaces, like for `org.json`

```
{
      "organization": {
          "id": "e768cffa-28e0-4b42-90af-f22a99d9aae9",
          "name": "season",
          "site": {
              "id": "bca39280-afbe-43ec-8b75-d1763addd953",
              "name": "season",
              "spaces": [
                  {
                      "id": "316b0e41-99e1-4748-88ef-e6d5bb0dbba2",
                      "name": "8F",
                      "isBottom": false,
                      "spaces": [
                          {
                              "id": "36a991c2-35da-42b4-9438-b6469179fa4b",
                              "name": "office",
                              "spaces": [],
                              "isBottom": true
                          },
                          {
                              "id": "39456064-0e1c-4b7c-8868-787f530de48f",
                              "name": "lobby",
                              "spaces": [],
                              "isBottom": true
                          },
                          {
                              "id": "89b8708b-4475-4454-8ec0-3de48d7a9663",
                              "name": "RD",
                              "spaces": [],
                              "isBottom": true
                          }
                      ]
                  },
                  {
                      "id": "ed9f51ef-b9df-4ab3-9b12-7a89d206b874",
                      "name": "ekopro",
                      "isBottom": true,
                      "spaces": []
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
  }
```

I tried using `dfs` to traversal all space nodes of tree.

```
import json


def traversal(obj, key, n, path, result):
    if n > 2:
        path['id'] = obj['id']
        path['spaces'] = []
    if n> 2 and not obj['spaces']:
        result.append(path)
        return


    for k, v in obj.items():

        if isinstance(v, dict):
            traversal(v, key, n + 1, dict(path), result)

        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for i in v:
                traversal(i, key, n + 1, dict(path), result)



def tree_path(json, key):
    result = []
    path = []
    if not json:
        return result
    traversal(json, key, 0, path, result)
    return result


file = open('org.json')
data = json.load(file)

print(tree_path(data, 'spaces'))
```

**Output**:

```
[
   {
      "id":"36a991c2-35da-42b4-9438-b6469179fa4b",
      "spaces":[]
   },
   {
      "id":"39456064-0e1c-4b7c-8868-787f530de48f",
      "spaces":[]
   },
   {
      "id":"89b8708b-4475-4454-8ec0-3de48d7a9663",
      "spaces":[]
   },
   {
      "id":"ed9f51ef-b9df-4ab3-9b12-7a89d206b874",
      "spaces":[]
   }
]
```

In the code above all spaces nodes sre printed, but I wanted to print the output like if it had multiple nested spaces. Somthing like this:

```
[
        {
            "id": "8553a4d1-062d-4a41-abe7-a629b67f5954",
            "spaces": [
                {
                    "id": "ed19abf8-ade5-43a3-b12b-a4e7e8ae3b3e",
                    "spaces": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "8651bdc9-676b-47e3-9ee5-fe00aa4d8151",
                    "spaces": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "151f5828-a04f-4ca6-b6ac-6b3238f74af0",
                    "spaces": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "0c556e08-7703-4cb6-9b33-632748678d17",
            "spaces": []
        }
   
]
```

Comment: In your required output you have: `"id":"87df..."`. Where does this `id` come from?

Comment: "id":"87df..." that is typo. In the required output that id had modified. It’s from the org.json object of spaces node of first child

Comment: Ok, I see you have changed your required output, but now, why is `"id": "bca39 ... "` present in `org.json`, but missing from your required output?

Comment: It's missing that cause the end condition is not good enough, the "id": "bca39 ..."  is covered by the leaf node.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try. I realize the output is slightly different than you wanted but it can be adapted to your liking.

```py
def traverse(obj, key):
    if key in obj:
        return {
            'id': obj['id'],
            key: [traverse(child, key) for child in obj[key]]
        }

    else:
        return [
            traverse(child, key) for child in 
            filter(
                lambda item: isinstance(item, dict) or isinstance(item, list), 
                obj.values()
            )
        ]

with open("./test.json", 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(json.dumps(traverse(data, 'spaces'), indent=2))
```

The resulting output:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "id": "bca39280-afbe-43ec-8b75-d1763addd953",
      "spaces": [
        {
          "id": "316b0e41-99e1-4748-88ef-e6d5bb0dbba2",
          "spaces": [
            {
              "id": "36a991c2-35da-42b4-9438-b6469179fa4b",
              "spaces": []
            },
            {
              "id": "39456064-0e1c-4b7c-8868-787f530de48f",
              "spaces": []
            },
            {
              "id": "89b8708b-4475-4454-8ec0-3de48d7a9663",
              "spaces": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "ed9f51ef-b9df-4ab3-9b12-7a89d206b874",
          "spaces": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Hi Ramzi. I tried your method it can be adapted into required output. Thanks for your help, have a nice day.

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).